# Show plain text in Gridview/DetailView

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I use kartik/GridView. In my database, I have following record using widget of \dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditor in _form.php:

```
<p>ist gew&ouml;hnungsbed&uuml;rftig aber halt auch kompetent</p>
```

Any ideas how to outline this record in GridView **without HTML-tags**, just plain text like this:

```
ist gewöhnungsbedürftig aber halt auch kompetent
```

Here is my DetailView:

```html
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;
?>
<div class="bewerber-view">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <h2><?= Html::encode($model->id) ?></h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <?php
        $gridColumn = [
            .
            .
  'beurteilung_persoenlich:ntext', //contains upper record
            .
            .
        ];

        echo DetailView::widget([
            'model' => $model,
            'attributes' => $gridColumn
        ]);
        ?>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

got solution by my own:

```html
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;
?>
<div class="bewerber-view">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <h2><?= Html::encode($model->id) ?></h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <?php
        $gridColumn = [
            .
            .
  'beurteilung_persoenlich:html', //contains upper record
            .
            .
        ];

        echo DetailView::widget([
            'model' => $model,
            'attributes' => $gridColumn
        ]);
        ?>
 
</div>
```

will solve my problem as described.
Happy Coding

Answer (score -1):

this worked for me

```
   'your_attritube_name:html'
```